# How do I get a button to display a label when clicked using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to make a button that displays a label when clicked. Here was my thinking:

```
from Tkinter import *

def write_hello():
    w = Label(root, text = "Hello. This is a label.")
    w.pack()

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text = "Hello!", command = write_hello() )
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone be nice enough to walk me through this? I'm very new.

Comment: Don't try to display a `Label` on a `Button`. Instead, change the `Button`' to contain the desired content of that `Label`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that?

Comment: You want `command=write_hello` (notice I didn't _call_ the function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `write_hello` function *before* you even create the button, so what you're probably seeing is the label showing up before the button on the UI (and without clicking it).  What you want to do is pass the *function* to the `Button` constructor instead of the function's return value:

```
button = Button(root, text = "Hello!", command = write_hello)
```